How to add/update security questions in Liferay DXP 7.4
When a user sign-in to Liferay, it ask user to select a security question and insert answer. This question is helpful in account recovery. My customer want to add custom security questions there. Can anybody help me, where can I add/update these questions in Liferay DXP 7.4?

Portal Administrators should configure the following properties in the portal-ext.properties file:
#
# Set this to true to enable reminder queries that are used to help reset a
# user's password.
#
users.reminder.queries.enabled=true
users.reminder.queries.custom.question.enabled=true

#
# Set this to false to enable users without a reminder query to reset their
# password.
#
users.reminder.queries.required=false

#
# Input a list of questions used for reminder queries.
#
users.reminder.queries.questions=what-is-your-primary-frequent-flyer-number,what-is-your-library-card-number,what-was-your-first-phone-number,what-was-your-first-teacher's-name,what-is-your-father's-middle-name

Then the signed user can choose customized questions.

Thanks Ben, it's working, fine, But big question is that, my website support multi-languaes. In that case how can I add questions in different languages? Is there any interface to add/edit those questions?

Control Panel / Configuration / Language Override.

Thanks Olaf it's working. You have always been a halping hand for Liferay dev's.
